# Trouble Storing SimpleXMLElement Object into Array

Tags: php, arrays, object, simplexml

```
Array ( [0] => 
   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [record] => 
   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [f] => 
                             Array ( [0] => Company 
                                     [1] => Company 
                                     [2] => Mark Test 
                                     [3] => Intern 
                                     [4] => Administrative 
                                     [5] => Account 
                                     [6] => img.png 
                                     [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 18 ) ) 
                                     [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 21 ) ) 
                                     [9] => emailtest@gmail.com 
                                     [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 178 ) ) 
                                     [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 177 ) ) 
                                     [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 179 ) ) 
                                     [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 168 ) ) ) 
                            [update_id] => 12102222262043 ) ) )
```

This is basically my simplexmlobject array that I want to somehow just manipulate and take out the data starting from the f element. I want to store like the words Company, Mark Test, Intern into an array. I can't seem to figure out how I am suppose to do this with a foreach loop in php and the structure of this is so crazy.

Well to get all the values for this data I did this in part of my code where getUsers() does an api call to a service that gives me a simplexml:

```
$xml = $getUser->getUsers();
$records = $xml->xpath('//records');

print_r($records);
```

Comment: So you want to take out everything after and including `f` in the document? Also, where did that enclosing `Array` come from? Can you post the code that generated this output?

Comment: yes I want all those elements into an array thats not so convoluted.

Comment: You're probably better off using DOMDocument instead of SimpleXML for this. I'd be happy to write an example using DOMDoment but SimpleXML is a bit too messy when it comes to this kind of stuff... I should know, I actually fixed a big with SimpleXML an array casting but it won't be out until the PHP 5.4 release.

Comment: hmm sure what do I have to lose its been a pain trying to do it this way :(

Comment: So just to clarify... what you want is an array of all `<records>` nodes or all children of `<records>` nodes?

Comment: Well depending on my query if the result comes out with two people who have the same name it would be more viable to have an array of all <records> nodes from my thought process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOMDocument class behaves a little better than SimpleXML in cases like this (when you want to do something slightly more complicated)...

First load the document:

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($filename);
```

Then get all the `<records>` nodes:

```php
// Get a list of all <records> nodes which you can then loop through with foreach
$records = $dom->getElementsByTagName('records');
```

To get the children of all the `<records>` nodes:

```php
$allChildren = array();
foreach ( $records as $recordSet ) {
   foreach( $recordSet->childNodes as $child ) {
     $allChildren[] = $child;
   }
}
```

Now lets say you want the value of `<first_name>` in the first `<records>` node:

```php
$value = $records->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('first_name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Note that the return values from `getElementsByTagName` are `DOMNodeList`s not arrays.

As an added bonus if you know Javascript, this class behaves very much like the DOM is Javascript.

See also:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Alright will try this and hopefully it turns out way better :) Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: You're welcome. Just reply to this thread if you get stuck on anything related to this code and I'll jump in and see what I can do.

Comment: Glad to hear it. In my opinion, SimpleXML describes the type of tasks you should be using it for not the ease of use. For even remotely complex tasks I prefer DOMDocument.